# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start new transaction (current thread already has a transaction

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, transactions, ignite

In a transactional approach in Ignite caches, we use a multi-threaded approach.

case 1: multiple threads insert in a cache (No locking) on the same key.

case 2: multiple threads read data from cache (In Transactional locking) with a similar key.

For case 2, we are getting below mentioned error,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start new transaction
>   (current thread already has a transaction): GridNearTxLocal
>   [mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], nearLocallyMapped=false,
>   colocatedLocallyMapped=false, needCheckBackup=null,
>   hasRemoteLocks=true, trackTimeout=false, lb=null, mvccTracker=null,
>   mvccOp=null, thread=Executor task launch worker for task 290,
>   mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], super=GridDhtTxLocalAdapter
>   [nearOnOriginatingNode=false, nearNodes=[], dhtNodes=[],
>   explicitLock=false, super=IgniteTxLocalAdapter [completedBase=null,
>   sndTransformedVals=false, depEnabled=false, txState=IgniteTxStateImpl
>   [activeCacheIds=[105038815], recovery=false, mvccEnabled=false,
>   txMap=[IgniteTxEntry [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=344, val=abc,
>   hasValBytes=false], cacheId=105038815, txKey=IgniteTxKey
>   [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=344, val=abc, hasValBytes=false],
>   cacheId=105038815], val=[op=READ, val=null], prevVal=[op=NOOP,
>   val=null], oldVal=[op=NOOP, val=null], entryProcessorsCol=null,
>   ttl=-1, conflictExpireTime=-1, conflictVer=null, explicitVer=null,
>   dhtVer=null, filters=null, filtersPassed=false, filtersSet=true,
>   entry=GridDhtDetachedCacheEntry [super=GridDistributedCacheEntry
>   [super=GridCacheMapEntry [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=344, val=abc,
>   hasValBytes=false], val=null, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=166176849,
>   order=1554721151514, nodeOrder=1], hash=-1768407104, extras=null,
>   flags=0]]], prepared=0, locked=true,
>   nodeId=962ec8e9-c7bd-4b73-b4d3-078da58f4439, locMapped=false,
>   expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=0, partUpdateCntr=0,
>   serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=166176849,
>   order=1554721151514, nodeOrder=44]]]], mvccWaitTxs=null,
>   qryEnlisted=false, forceSkipCompletedVers=false, super=IgniteTxAdapter
>   [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=166176849, order=1554721151514,
>   nodeOrder=44], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=3770,
>   startTime=1554721555785, nodeId=6fb5bb88-fc57-478e-9fb9-c26cc8a311e8,
>   startVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=166176849, order=1554721151514,
>   nodeOrder=44], endVer=null, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ,
>   concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false,
>   plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null,
>   state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion
>   [topVer=44, minorTopVer=0], txCounters=null, duration=156ms,
>   onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]]]

Code Snippet as below,

```
IgniteCache<String, String> cache =  ignite.getOrCreateCache("ABC_CACHE");
Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC, TransactionIsolation.REPEATABLE_READ);

String acknowledge = cache.get(key);
if(acknowledge == null || acknowledge.length() == 0) {
if(acknowledge.contains("xyz")) {
    acknowledge.append("mln");
}
    flag = true;
    cache.removeAsync(key);
}else {
    cache.putAsync(key, acknowledge);
}
tx.commit();
tx.close();
```

Also, tried with Isolation level **READ_COMMITTED**, no error occurred but, could not achieve transaction locking. Can anyone explain where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Just curious why you need async methods if it's a single method and you're commiting it next anyway.

Comment: Does it have any impact? But yes I tried with put with sync. Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe indeed you failed to close some transaction.

My recommendation is to open transaction in `try()` clause, and `close()` it in `finally{}`

Comment: Error is solved but the transactional approach is lost. Appending one more point multi threads which I mentioned are running on different JVM.

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting at. Please note that you can `suspend()` an ignite `Transaction` in one thread and `resume()` in other one. Give it a try if you depend on multi-threading in a single tx.